# Parse json data using- GSON - android

Tags: android, gson

I got below json response:

```
          {
        "session_id":"3c59ba77-8545-4de7-aae0-41a5s1fads19",
        "user-info":{"username":"ganesh","website":null,"location":"newyork","bio":null,"ask":null,"name":"ganesh","isSelf":true}
         }
```

how to create model class for this response:

Unable to create object name for user-info

How to parse this data using GSON?

[image]

[image]

Comment: is it `user_info` or `user-info`? change `-` to `_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create GSON parser with a `FieldNamingPolicy`

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_DASHES).create();
```

It would then convert standard Java naming convention `userInfo` to `user-info` (illegal in Java as a variable name) and vice versa.

But in your case separators are mixed (once dash, once underscore).

So there is another solution, set the name using annotation

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

[..]

@SerializedName("user-info")
User_info userInfo;
```